# NMath IIS access denied

Tags: asp.net, iis, nmath

I have tried using the NMath library on a
ASP.NET 4 web application hosted in IIS. While it works perfectly o the development machine, on the server it throws this exception:

> Unable to load DLL 'nmath_native_x86.dll': Access is denied.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'nmath_native_x86.dll': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'nmath_native_x86.dll':
>   Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))]
>   CenterSpace.NMath.Kernel.DotNetBlas.ca985db1fb290841a533a3547ace1ae2b(Int32*
>   ca9e3f1c0641beace93cb8eb4a27060d6, Double*
>   cf339080161dff75cfd1b46a10c2eec70, Int32*
>   c757a2154665e6da4d820f8c504ec2601, Double*
>   c00a69c4fa5b6d809b68a96ca184dcf79, Int32*
>   c1565590bf448d2c630952a0391360cc3) +0
>   CenterSpace.NMath.Kernel.DotNetBlas.copy(Int32 n, DoubleDataBlock x,
>   Int32 xOffset, Int32 incx, DoubleDataBlock y, Int32 yOffset, Int32
>   incy) +149    CenterSpace.NMath.Core.DoubleVector.set_Item(Slice
>   slice, DoubleVector value) +165

While i have read around here that it might be related the the
permissions of the [AppPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109299/iis-7-unable-to-load-dll-access-denied) or something similar, I can't seem to point down the problem. What could it be?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a couple of options.

1) Is the C++ runtime installed? NMath can't load a native dll without it. See the deployment section here: http://centerspace.net/doc/NMath/user/overview-83427.htm#Xoverview-83427

2) Perhaps you're not configuring NMath correctly? You can do NMathConfiguration.NativeLocation to point to a location. More here:

http://centerspace.net/doc/NMathSuite/ref/html/T_CenterSpace_NMath_Core_NMathConfiguration.htm

Finally, please generate log file using NMathConfiguration.LogLocation. The resulting log file will tell you what's wrong.

- Trevor